# Ether has +R effect nd CH3 has +I effect, if R effect is more effective than I effect then why is CH3COOH less acidic than CH3OCH2COOH

Tags: organic-chemistry

The More is the electron donating effect, the more will be the charge on carboxylate ion, the more will it be unstable and the less acidic it will be.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't comparing $\ce{–CH3}$ with $\ce{–OCH3}$. You're comparing $\ce{–CH3}$ with $\ce{–CH2OCH3}$, as these are the groups actually attached to the carboxyl groups in your two acids. In the latter group the saturated  $\ce{CH2}$ function prevents delocalization of any electron pairs from the oxygen and bl9cks the proposed +R effect.

Comment: So what type of group is CH2OCH3 then?

Comment: Only the inductive effect can pass through a saturated atim, and the oxygen is electronegative. What does that suggest to you?

Comment: Actually I knew ethers have -I effect but, as u said that oxygen is not directly attached to the carboxyl group, and CH2 is also attached to it, so I was saying won't it donate the electrons to the carboxyl group, since O is farther away to -COOH it's inductive effect will decrease and CH2 is nearer and it's inductive effect will dominate!??

Comment: CH2 is not that good a donor, the more electronegative oxygen still dominates even one position removed.